# remove part of string from textbox with Replace

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net

I have a string in textbox like this

```
 xxxxxxxxxxx    310041              xxxxx   xxxxxx    xxxx xxxx
  RTE STAT: 00 AUTH ID RESP:         ERR FLAG: 0   PEM: M (02)   ATC: 000000
    RVSL REASON: 00       TELLER/SERIAL:          /         TERM CAP: 5 (EMV)
```

i need to remove this  `RTE STAT: 00 AUTH ID RESP:         ERR FLAG: 0` to

```
txtRemark.Text.Replace("  RTE STAT: 00 AUTH ID RESP:         ERR FLAG: 0   ", "")
```

but nothing happened i try with regex but it's not happened too

result must be like this

```
 xxxxxxxxxxx    310041              xxxxx   xxxxxx    xxxx xxxx
 PEM: M (02)   ATC: 000000
 TERM CAP: 5 (EMV)
```

Comment: Did you assign the value to the `txtRemark.Text`? `txtRemark.Text = txtRemark.Text.Replace("  RTE STAT: 00 AUTH ID RESP:         ERR FLAG: 0   ", "")`

Comment: my example is the `txtRemark.Text` value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1), the `.Replace` method yields back the replace string. You will need to change your code from `txtRemark.Text.Replace("  RTE STAT: 00 AUTH ID RESP:         ERR FLAG: 0   ", "")` to `txtRemark.Text = txtRemark.Text.Replace("  RTE STAT: 00 AUTH ID RESP:         ERR FLAG: 0   ", "")`.